# Folder structure and imports

Tags: python, import

So I have a small project i'm working on currently but im struggling with imports.
originally I had a struct like so:

```
root -> python
     -> tests  -> testscripts
```

Im running my tests from the python folder and I had a class in that folder called pertest_resources that contained paths to other folders like the root and the script folder.

```
python_folder = os.path.realpath(os.curdir)
perf_root_folder = os.path.realpath(python_folder + "/../")
test_root_folder = os.path.realpath(python_folder + "/../tests")
script_folder = os.path.realpath(test_root_folder + "/scripts")
network_folder = os.path.realpath(test_root_folder + "/networks")
output_folder = os.path.realpath(test_root_folder + "/output")
input_folder = os.path.realpath(test_root_folder + "/input")
kit_folder = os.path.realpath(perf_root_folder + "/kit")
sys.path.append(python_folder)
sys.path.append(script_folder)
sys.path.append(network_folder)
```

Now this worked fine when all the core files were in the python folder, but now its getting a little messy i've been asked to branch off some of the python scripts to a new folder called 'networks' with a structure like:

```
root -> python -> perftest_resources.py
     -> tests  -> testscripts
               -> networks -> standard_network.py
```

Now I want to run a file from the python folder called test that uses the standard_network that in turn imports perftest_resources from the python folder.

I've tried:

```
sys.path.append('..' + os.sep + '..') 
from python.perftest_resources import PerfTestResources as pr
```

but that doesn't work when its all originally run from test.py in the python folder.
Do I need to add init to both folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a package? If true, you should use `intra-package references`, like

```
from . import echo
from .. import formats
from ..filters import equalizer
```

If not, turn it into package )

Read more: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: It could be a package really, probably the neatest way to do it really. It was just developed with odd imports inside so means abit of refactoring.

Comment: Anyway if it is not a homework project, you will have to build it into a package/module. You need meta information, automatic requirements management by pip and finally deployment. So, I see no other way but just to proceed with packaging

Comment: Alright thanks! It is just an internal thing currently but I suppose packaging would be the best choice in the long run.